# How to separate vue js file code from laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am currently working on Laravel 5.3 and Vue Js, i have following structure of application.

1. resource/view/layouts/plane.blade.php (works as master.blade.php)
2. resource/view/layouts/dashboard.blade.php (works as child.blade.php - extends plane)
3. resource/view/index.blade.php (current blade file - extends dashboard)
4. public/js/blog.js

   **plane.blade.php code**

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" class="no-js">
            <head>
                   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
                   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blog.js"></script>

             </head>
              <body>
                     @yield('body')
              </body>
        </html>
   ```

   **dashboard.blade.php code**

   ```
    @extends('layouts.plane')

    @section('body')
           <div class="row" id="manage-vue">
               @yield('section')
          </div>

     @stop
   ```

   **index.blade.php code**

   ```
    @extends('layouts.dashboard') 

    @section('page_heading','Blog')

    @section('section')



   <div >

       @{{ message }}

   </div>

   @stop
   ```

   **blog.js code**

   ```
       var myModel =  new Vue({
          el: '#manage-vue',
          data: {
              message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
          }
      });
   ```

   With these separate files, i am not getting result, as it shows error **Cannot find element: #app**.

   If i place category.js code in index.blade.php file, i get correct result.

   How can i work with separate files ?

Comment: Laravel now ships with vue, so it's probably easier to use the default setup: `npm install` and then use [elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) to compile your js assets

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the `blog.js` **after** the `#app` element.

Comment: did not work form me. it does not showing error but also not result.

Comment: where did you put your vue.js on the blade template? Please include the code for that blade template on your question.

Comment: it's clear you aren't move the `blog.js` after the `#manage-vue`... Try to move everything (`vue.js` script and `blog.js` file) to beneath the `#manage-vue` element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `el` you have to use [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Basics) like following:

```
 var myModel =  new Vue({
       template: '#app',
       data: {
           message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
       }
   });
```

And you have to have following in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="app">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</script>
```